# Let Over Lambda: symbolic representation in macros

Tags: macros, lisp, metaprogramming

Doug Hoyte defines in his introduction to *Let Over Lambda* the symb function as an essential utility to meta-programming with macros:

In clisp:

```
(defun mkstr (&rest args)
  (with-output-to-string (s)
    (dolist (a args) (princ a s))))

(defun symb (&rest args)
  (values (intern (apply #'mkstr args))))
```

Why are symbols so important in macro programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols are how things are named in Lisp, and macros often want to talk about names.

Imagine you want to write your own version of `defstruct`: well a form like

```
(defstruct pos x y)
```

is going to need to create names -- symbols -- like `pos-x`, `make-pos`, `pos-p` and so on.  So you need ways of talking about symbols: creating symbols from other ones, creating secret symbols which only you know about and which are different than any other symbols and so on.

I kind of disagree that the `symb` function he defines is *essential*, but you do need to be able to manipulate symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Symbols *name* functions and macros, so if your macro defines functions, it will have to construct symbols.

E.g., when you do `(defstruct foo a b c)`, you are defining these functions:

1. `MAKE-FOO`
2. `FOO-P`
3. `COPY-FOO`
4. `FOO-A`
5. `FOO-B`
6. `FOO-C`
7. `(SETF FOO-A)`
8. `(SETF FOO-B)`
9. `(SETF FOO-C)`

which requires constructing the 6 symbols above.

PS. You might find the output of `(macroexpand-1 (defstruct foo a b c))` instructive.